# convert protobuf to other protobuf

Tags: protobuf-java

I have reading Protobuf from Kaka so finally I'm getting a generated Java Object.
I would like to rename/create other Protobuf based on the original I got.

let say I have 2 classes A and B.
my code listen to Kafka topic and gets A.
I would like to "convert" A to B which is almost the same Object (few variable name changes).
is there any way to overwrite Protobuf Parser? in order to Generate B instead of A?

for example:

```
Class A{
String aa;
int aaaa;
}

Class B{
String bb;
int bbbb;
}
```

my Listener gets A and i would like to get B (bb=aa, bb=aaaa

Answer (score 2):

Assuming A and B are compatible (same tags have the same type), you can serialize back your proto and parse it again.
This will also work if some tags are missing in one object, but parsing will mostly fail if two tags exists with the different types.

Proto:

```
Message A {
  string aa = 1;
  int32 aaaa = 2;
  int32 a_only = 3;
}

Message B {
  string bb = 1;
  int32 bbbb = 2;
  string b_only = 4;  // Must not be 3.
}
```

Java:

```
A a = GetAFromQueue();
B b = B.parseFrom(a.toByteArray());
```

Another (probably better) option would be to get a the message from Kafka as a byte array and to parse it into a A or into a B as needed. This avoids re-serializing the data, though the same tags with different type issue is still relevant.

```
byte[] data = GetDataFromQueue();
A a = A.parseFrom(data);
[...]
B b = B.parseFrom(data);
```